# Asp.net Calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net calendar control that is used to select a date and store it in a database.  It is also adding the time which makes reporting difficult.  We only need the date not the time.  How can I prevent the calendar control from including the time....or making the time the same for every date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime has a Date property, `DateTime.Date` that will return just the date with 00:00:00 for the time.

So, when reading the calendar.SelectedDate, use `calendar.SelectedDate.Date`. This still returns a DateTime but with a zeroed time.

When rendering a DateTime without the time, use ToString("dd/mm/yyyy").

Comment: Daniel, when you say DateTime has a Date property are you talking about the actual database column where the date is stored?

Comment: No, the .NET DateTime class. Before saving it to the database you can call that to just save the date and drop the time, but the DateTime value returned by the Calendar.SelectedDate will always return a Date and a time, hence the name DateTime. So what you should do is drop the time by calling Date and then when you display the date, use the dateformat "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy" depending on your preference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd filter the Date in the backend using the `DateTime.Date` value, which zeros the time.